# gdal_grid not recognising .xyz file

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, xyz, gdal-grid

I'm trying to use GDAL, specifically `gdal_grid` to grid an xyz dataset.

However when I run my command I am getting the error `` ERROR 4: `C:\Users\Public\clip.xyz' not recognized as a supported file format. `` but I know that xyz is a raster driver of GDAL, so I'm confused as to why it's unsupported?

The command I am trying to run is the below:

```
gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1=2.25:radius2=2.25:nodata=0 -of GTiff C:\Users\Public\clip.xyz C:\Users\Public\clip_gridded.tif
```

Comment: Shouldn't gdal_grid input be a vector file? You may want to convert the XYZ to CSV and create a VRT for it to be recognized.

Comment: If it truly is a file with the correct format that GDAL recognises as XYZ, you  can just use `gdal_translate`.